# Submenu Pushes Parent Menu Items Apart On Hover in Modified WordPress TwentyTwelve

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I'm working on a WordPress site that uses the modified version of TwentyTweve theme.

My job is to modify the navigation dropdown menu, to make it push the content down when the dropdown submenus appear on hover.

Problem: when the submenus drop down, they somehow push the parent menu items apart.

I want to force the parent items to remain in place. Would appreciate help from a CSS / WordPress guru!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In style.css, line 1515 you should find these width attributes:

```
width: 180px;
width: 12.85714286rem;
```

These are the attributes that specify the width of the sub menus and "push the parent menu items apart".

Comment: thank you very much! So what should I do – just delete them? Or replace them with something?

Comment: – commented them out, nothing changed, the parent menu items are still pushed apart.

Comment: Here's where it get's tricky. You're sub menu items are quite a lot longer then your top level menu. That's why simply commenting them out won't do it, as the length of the sub menu text will push them apart. If you want the content to be pushed down as well, you'll need to set a width that is the same for both top level and submenu items.

Comment: If you don't mind the content not getting pushed down, you could try something like this in the css: `.sub-menu {position: absolute;top: 28px;}`

Comment: I think you're onto something! But please stay with me for a sec. First, I do have to have the content pushed down, unfortunately. Second: I tried to set margin-left for .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul – and it partially solved the problem. However, About and Investors link behave a bit differently. Could you take a look now, please? If you could help me figure out the reason and solution, I'd be grateful.

Comment: They behave the same for me (or at least as they should), but I would change it from margin-left to margin-right, so it would be `margin-right: -140px;` and it will align better with it's parent top menu.

Comment: – I do have one more question though, since it's clear to me you know what you're doing. How can I arrange the submenu items not vertically, but neatly along the entire width of the main content area? (By the way, I think it would be appropriate if I ask it as a separate question. Would you consider helping me with that issue, too?)

Comment: – in case you find a moment to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975772/arrange-drop-down-submenu-items-horizontally-wrapped-modified-twentytwelve-wor

Comment: Thanks! And yes sure I'll take a look. If I think I can add any value then I'll comment/get an answer up on there ;)

Comment: I've just checked that question but the site is behaving much differently now. Also it would help others answer that question in particular if you post the html and even the relevant css.

Comment: Sorry, @Omega, I couldn't help trying to solve it myself, but failing so far. I got it back to the way it was, could you please take another look?

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added my take on it. It's quite labor intensive but it depends how much you want that layout I guess.