# Arrange Drop-Down Submenu Items Horizontally, Wrapped (Modified TwentyTwelve WordPress Theme)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation, html-lists

The site I'm working on uses the modified WordPress TwentyTwelve theme. The standard drop-down menu of that theme has been modified to push the content down when the submenu opens:

**Problem:** I want to arrange the sub-menus neatly along the entire width of the content area (960px wide), rather than having them drop down under each other. If the number of submenu items is large, I want the submenu to wrap over several lines, but have the items arranged in neat vertical rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I see it. Currently your sub menus are constrained to its parent menu. To achieve what you want, I think you'd need to do quite a lot of restructuring. I would keep your sub menus separate and place them directly underneath your main menu. You can code your sub menu items to take up the 960px width (by hand I know, even though you're using wordpress), and if needs be set the longer sub menu into two lines. Give each sub menu a unique id and set them to display:none in css. Your main menus li's already have unique identifiers so then you can create css rules for the specific li's. Something like this:

```
#menu-item-58:hover + #submenu1 {display:block;}
#submenu1 {display:none;}
#submenu1:hover{display:block;} //so submenu doesn't disappear when mouse hovers over.
```

Here is an example where you can see in action, I've used div's but you can change it accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/H3WB6/

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to experiment with that, @Omega, but I suspect I may have more questions to you about that. I still hadn't quite figure out how to contact a specific person on StackOverflow, what would be the best way to ask you further questions, if I may, of course?

Comment: By the way, Ive never seen + sign in CSS before, what does it mean?

Comment: It's just getting your html right, so your submenu items take up the correct spacing. Then you use the css method above to show/hide when needed. That's just my take on it anyway. Others may have better solutions, possibly using javascript/jquery... The + targets the matching element given (#submenu1) directly after #menu-item-58:hover... I think you create a chat room then invite users I believe.

Comment: Okay. @Omega, I think I figured out how to access individual menu items and submenu items for that particular menu – but could you explain to me this in a little more detail, please: "You can code your sub menu items to take up the 960px width (by hand I know, even though you're using wordpress), and if needs be set the longer sub menu into two lines." What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I was suggesting that you separate your submenu by copying the current html code for the submenu and placing it underneath where your top level menu ends. Then something like `#submenu1 li a {float:left;width:20%}` would give your first submenu equal spacing for it's five items. So it's basically meant to get your submenu items to fill the 960px space.

Comment: I've just checked the site and have seen some changes. Try this as a solution in it's current state `#menu-item-58 + .sub-menu {margin-left: 154px;}` to align the About submenu.

Comment: Thank you, @Omega – I almost figured it out. I only have a couple of issues to solve: how to fill the empty area of "Investors" submenu at the bottom right corner, and how to set a little more space at the bottom of the submenu links and a little less space at the top. Would appreciate your input, if you can think of something!

Comment: I figured out the latter one (by setting the proper padding top and bottom) – but still struggling with the first issue. Would appreciate advice from you, @Omega.

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov how about extending the last item to fill the space up? It would mean that the last items "clickable area" is wider though. `#menu-item-35 a {width: 342px;}`

Comment: – that would be a great solution, if I knew for sure that the last item is always in that place. But what if the client adds or removes some menu items?

Comment: If items are added or removed then it won't fill the space. We should be ab;e to specify a rule to target the last item without using it's id, but once an item is added or removed then it won't work still.

Comment: I'm thinking of putting a div somehow behind the bottom line of the submenu, about 3px above the image, of the same color as the background of the links. Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Comment: Possibly, then you could use margin-top:-25px to push it up. You'd likely need to use some css to show this div only when the sub menu is display also. Could you add a div directly below the menu, to try out?

Comment: Hm... because of the placing of the menu and logo with the whole bunch of mutually contradicting floats, the masking tape divm even though placed under the menu, ends up on top of it.

Comment: your advice is definitely in the right direction, but how do I use css to show this div only when the sub menu is display also?

Comment: Okay great. Now just the show/hide effect on hover, first set display:none for #masking-tape

Comment: Okay, I set it to display:none. Thank you! How do I set it to display:block on hover?

Comment: Can you set display:none for #masking-tape in the .css file and not as an inline style please.

Comment: OK. Done. Set all the styles for masking-tape in the css.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28132/discussion-between-dimitri-vorontzov-and-omega)